# How can I manipulate the result of VLOOKUP function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If VLOOKUP doesn't find a match, it returns something that looks like "#____".
However, I want to manipulate the VLOOKUP formula not to write anything in the cell if it doesn't find a match. (This picture is from Turkish Excel.)

How can I get VLOOKUP to return an empty result if it doesn't find anything?

[image]

Comment: " Manupilate "?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to add an IF / ISNA command to the Vlookup function

> =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(**`YOUR LOOKUP`**,FALSE)),"**`VALUE HERE`**",VLOOKUP(**`YOUR LOOKUP`**,FALSE))

You need to make sure that the last parameter or the Vlookup is set to false, and where I wrote Value Here, you need to keep the quotes, but simply have a blank space if you want it to be blank.

If your Vlookup command was : `=VLOOKUP(B7,testsheet,2)` and you wanted the value to be blank if it doesn't exist, you would use:

> =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B7,testsheet,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(B7,testsheet,2,FALSE))

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Excel 2007 you can use the IFERROR function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LookupCell,LookupTable,Column,Type),"")
```

It's cleaner looking and more efficient than Wil's version but it is not backward compatible. If you share your xls w/ an Excel 2003 user the formula will error. In that case I would use Wil's method.